# Pip egg name for editable dependency changes

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have a custom dependency which I specify with the -e flag in my requirements.txt:

```
...
-e git+git@git.myproject/projectname.git@master#egg=projectname-master
...
```

With this in place `pip install -r requirements.txt` works fine.

And pip freeze gives the following output:

```
...
-e git+git@git.myproject/projectname.git@b3d61ba97029316b5790a6d0328d59816262153d#egg=projectname-master
...
```

Which is what I would expect.

When running `pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt`followed by `pip freeze`however I get the following output.

```
...
-e git+git@git.myproject/projectname.git@4c58322b1750d6c3d2bde67f8a1657a09c45dbb9#egg=projectname-origin_HEAD
...
```

Note that the egg name here changed.

When writing the output of `pip freeze`to a requirements.txt file and running `pip install -r requirements` I get the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement projectname-master (from projectname-origin-HEAD->-r requirements.txt (line 13)) (from  versions: )
```

How do I stop pip from messing up the eggname on upgrade. This is necessary because I want to be able to lock the commits by writing the output of `pip freeze` to a file.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of packages you shouldn't rely on pip freeze. It will always try to add a commit SHA1 and effectively pin you package. If you want to be able to update a package you should edit the git URL in your requirements.txt file and remove all references to a specific commit, only point it to a branch name or a tag. This will have a performance penalty as every time the requirements.txt file is evaluated a check for latest version has to be done.

E.g. just keep this in your requirements.txt:

`-e git+git@git.myproject/projectname.git@master#egg=projectname`

Note that I removed the -master from the #egg: I don't think it's a good idea to name the egg any different then the name of the project. When I try to use another name then the name specified in the package's setup.py I get a Warning like this when pip install teh packages:

`Running setup.py -> Warning :: egg_info for package projectname-master produced metadata for project name projectname. Fix your #egg=projectname-master fragments.`

A bit more detail can be found here:
http://codeinthehole.com/tips/using-pip-and-requirementstxt-to-install-from-the-head-of-a-github-branch/

And here:
https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html